# How to test the correct implementation of special polynomials?

Tags: java, unit-testing, math, testing

I need to implement the calculation of some special polynomials in Java (the language is not really important). These are calculated as a weighted sum of a number of base polynomials with fixed coefficients.

Each base polynomial has 2 to 10 coefficients and there are typically 10 base polynomials considered, giving a total of, say 20-50 coefficients.

Basically the calculation is no big deal but I am worried about typos. I only have a printed document as a template. So i would like to implement unit tests for the calculations. The issue is: How do I get reliable testing data. I do have another software that is supposed to calculate these functions but the process is complicated and also error prone - I would have to scale the input values, go through a number of menu selections in the software to produce the output and then paste it to my testing code.

I guess that there is no way around using the external software to generate some testing data, but maybe you have some ***recommendations for making this type of testing procedure safer or minimize the required number of test cases***.

I am also worried about providing suitable input values: Depending on the value of the independent variable, certain terms will only have a tiny contribution to the output, while for other values they might dominate.

The types of errors I expect (and need to avoid) are:

- Typos in coefficients
- Coefficients applied to wrong power (i.e. `a_7*x^6` instead of `a_7*x^7` - just for demonstration, I am not calculating this way but am using Horner's scheme)
- Off-by one errors (i.e. missing zero order or highest order term)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a polynomial of degree 10, testing at 11 distinct points should give certainty.

However, already a test at one well-randomized point, `x=1.23004` to give an idea (away from small fractions like 2/3, 4/5), will with high probability show a difference if there is an error, because it is unlikely that the difference between the wrong and the true polynomial has a root at exactly this place.